# Shell : Adding list of prefix(strings) from a file to each and every domains in another file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a huge dictionary prefix of about `3000`in a file (`prefix.txt`).

```
#prefix.txt
mail
ns1
japan
server
ftp
......
```

another file( domains.txt) will have 11,000 domains.

```
#domains.txt
1,google.com
2,box.com
3,cnn.com
4,bbc.com
......
```

For each domain in `domains.txt`, I have to insert the list of prefix(3000) to it.

```
#Example ( Final.txt) : 
1,mail.google.com
1,ns1.google.com
1,japan.google.com
1,server.google.com
1,ftp.google.com
.............
```

I know the combination will give around (3000*11000=33Million) subdomains.

Honestly,I'm not familiar in shell/bash scripting. Can someone give any advice on how to achieve this ?

Comment: @user : Checking at it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Arun, i would use some scripting language for that, for example Python - would it be an option for you?

Comment: @MaxU shell logic would be good max . Python is a good optional part. But these days,I prefer text processing works can be done easier in shell rather than in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next} {for (prefix in a) { print prefix "." $0 }}' prefix.txt domains.txt
```

EDIT:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next} {for (prefix in a) { split($0, arr, ","); print arr[1] "," prefix "." arr[2] }}' prefix.txt domains.txt
```

Comment: Thank you on suggesting using awk.

Comment: If i add ID to the domains.txt and separated by delimiter by ",". ID,Domain. How to add the IDs to the result?